# Writing Curl POST in R

Tags: r, curl

What is the correct way of writing this Curl POST in R? 
I would like to have R read the contents of a file as "values" in the post form.

```
curl -X POST https://api.priceapi.com/jobs \  
   -d "token=token" \  
   -d "country=country" \  
   -d "source=source" \  
   -d "currentness=currentness" \  
   -d "completeness=completeness" \  
   -d "key=key" \  
   -d 'values=<values>'
```

So far I have this-

```
library(RCurl)  
library(RJSONIO)  
url = "https://api.priceapi.com/jobs"  
file.name = ".../output 1 .txt"  
results = postForm(url, token="token",   
                    country="country,  
                    source="source",   
                    currentness="currentness",  
                    completeness="completeness,  
                    key="key",  
                    values=fileUpload(filename = file.name))
```

It returns "Error: Bad Request"
I also tried it using httr post request-

```
r = POST(url, body = list(token="token",   
                    country="country,  
                    source="source",   
                    currentness="currentness",  
                    completeness="completeness,  
                    key="key",  
                    values=upload_file(file.name)) )
```

Here upload_file is not uploading the contents of the file but, I am guessing it is passing the path to the file (as a string) into the "values" parmeter.
Naturally that does not return the correct results.

The result of the httr POST request is;

```
  Response [https://api.priceapi.com/jobs]
  Date: 2016-12-13 10:11
  Status: 400
  Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
  Size: 228 B
{
    "success": false,
    "reason": "parameter value invalid",
    "parameter": "value",
    "valid values": "An array or a string containing values separated by newline",
    "comment": "Make sure the parameter 'value' has a valid value!"
```

Comment: Run `values = upload_file(file.name)` separately and see what the `values` object looks like. If it contains more than just the file path then you might need to do something like `as.character(upload_file(file.name))`. You could also try passing the file type to the `type` parameter inside `upload_file()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could solve this by using

```
file=readLines(".../output 1.txt")
inputValues <- paste(file,collapse="\n")
```

and then passing `inputValues` in the `values` parameter.